# Tokenize and capture with sed

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Suppose we have a string like
`"dir1|file1|dir2|file2"`

and would like to turn it into
`"-f dir1/file1 -f dir2/file2"`

Is there an elegant way to do this with sed or awk for a general case of n > 2?

My attempt was to try

`echo "dir1|file1|dir2|file2" | sed 's/\(\([^|]\)|\)*/-f \2\/\4 -f \6\/\8/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk -F'|' '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "-f %s/%s%s", $i, $(i+1), ((i==NF-1) ? "\n" : " ") }'  \
  <<<"dir1|file1|dir2|file2"
```

- `-F'|'` splits the input into fields by `|`
- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)` loops over the field indices in increments of 2
- `printf "-f %s/%s%s", $i, $(i+1), ((i==NF-1) ? "\n" : " ")` prints pairs of consecutive fields joined with `/` and prefixed with `-f<space>`

  - `((i==NF-1) ? "\n" : " ")` terminates each field-pair either with a space, if more fields follow, or a `\n` to terminate the overall output.

---

In a comment, the OP suggests a shorter variation, which may be of interest if you don't need/want the output to be `\n`-terminated:

```
awk -F'|' '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) printf "%s", (i%2 ? " -f " $i : "/" $i ) }' \
  <<<"dir1|file1|dir2|file2"
```

Comment: I saw your previous version, and based on that came up with this, which is a bit shorter then your current suggestion: `echo "dir1|file1|dir2|file2" | awk -F'|' '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) printf (i%2 ? " -f " $i : "/" $i ) }'`

Comment: Thanks, @IvanP., that's an interesting alternative - your solution doesn't add a trailing `\n` - which may actually be preferred, depending on use case - I've added it to the answer. Note that it's safer to use `printf "%s", ...` rather than passing the string as the _1st_ argument to `printf`, because the latter subjects the string to possibly unwanted interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\)|\?/-f \1\/\2 /g;s/ $//' file
```

This will work for `dir1|file1|dir2|file2|dirn|filen` type strings

The regexp forms two back references (`\1,\2 used in the replacement part of the substitution command s/pattern/replacement/)`, the first is all non-`|`'s, then a `|`, the second is all non-`|`'s then an optional `|` i.e. for the first application of the substitution (N.B. the `g` flag is implemented and so the substitutions may be multiple) `dir1` becomes `\1` and `file1` becomes `\2`. All that remains is to prepend `-f` and replace the first `|` by `/` and the second `|` by a space. The last space is not needed at the end of the line and is removed in the second substitution command.

Comment: Nicely done; you can make it work with both GNU and BSD Sed (by using `-E` the regex actually becomes simpler): `sed -E 's/([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|?/-f \1\/\2 /g;s/ $//' file`

Comment: Could you please add an explanation of what each part of the command does?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS='|' 'NR%2{p=$0;next} {printf " -f %s/%s", p, $0}' <<< 'dir1|file1|dir2|file2'
 -f dir1/file1 -f dir2/file2
```

Comment: ++ for brevity; to add an explanation: `-v RS='|'` splits the input into _records_ by `|`; `NR%2{p=$0;next}` saves each record with an _odd_ record number (`NR`; starts at `1`) in variable `p` for later use and skips to the next record (`next`); `{printf "-f %s/%s", p, $0}'` is then only executed for _even_-record-number records and prints the prefix (`-f `), followed by the previous record stored in `p`, joined with a `/` with the current record (`$0`).
The last record actually includes the trailing `\n` added to the input string by `<<<`, which is why the overall output has a trailing `\n`.

Comment: (P.S.: Most likely it doesn't matter here, but this solution wouldn't work if the input contained _multiple_ lines of strings like the sample input string.)

Answer (score 0):

A gnu-awk solution:

```
s="dir1|file1|dir2|file2"
awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="[^|]+\\|[^|]+" } {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
       sub(/\|/, "/", $i);
       if (i>1)
          printf " ";
       printf "-f " $i
    };
    print ""
}' <<< "$s"
-f dir1/file1 -f dir2/file2
```

`FPAT` is used for grabbing `dir1|file2` into single field.